# Upsampling feature maps in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to implement a convolution-deconvolution network for a image segmentation project. In the deconvolution part, I am planning to upsample the feature map by 2. e.g. The original feature map is of dimension 64*64*4 and I want to upsample it into 128*128*4. Does anyone know a tensor operation that does this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for an upsampling operator and not conv2d_transpose?

Answer (score 7):

You could use `tf.image.resize_images()`. It takes batches of images or single images and supports the most common methods such as `bilinear` and `nearest_neighbor`.

Here's the link to the TensorFlow API reference: [resizing](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/image.html#resizing)

You can also take a look at how the upsampling operation is implemented in a higher-level API such as [tflearn](http://tflearn.org/). You can find `upsample_2d` and `upscore_layer` in their Github repo:  [conv.py](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/layers/conv.py)

**Note:** the output might be cast to `tf.float32` in older TF versions